# Images as planes rendered as pink when i render with GPU

Tags: rendering, workflow

When I use the GPU Nvidia Geforce card instead of the CPU, some of the the images-as-planes are rendered pink.  There does not seem to be a reason for which image is not rendered properly.  The images are on different layers and it seems like the GPU prefers rendering layers 2 and 3 which are much simpler than layer 1.  One of the layers rendered with pink empty areas the first render, but rendered correctly on a second render attempt.

Is there something i can do to fix this problem?  Does this ever happen with CPU?  Is it possible to 'upset' Blender by moving things around to different layers after having them on one layer for many months?  I just started using the GPU, after using CPU for a while, could this be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the Nvidia GeForce card drivers are up to date? What happens if you render the problem scene with CPU? This may be a hardware problem, rather than a blender one, and you might want to ask it instead on [Hardware](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: Ok, this may be terrible silly question, but apparently I need to update driver when the pop-up box appears on my screen?  It has come up many times but i ignored it !  I thought my card might be too old too update and maybe trying to update the driver would render the card unusable.

Comment: The card is a GeForce GT 610.  Can I update it or is it too old?  The CPU renders everything just fine (so far) but it seems to take a long time to do so!  I just want to make sure that moving things to different layers is not going to cause some terrible unexpected problem.

Comment: In my opinion, if your card is a GT 610 with only 48 cuda cores and one GB of VRAM,  you might be better off rendering in CPU. So few cores might be slower and more limited than most modern CPUs...

Comment: The CPU in this computer is Intel Core 2 Duo  E7300  2.66GHz.  I have 4 GB of RAM.  Should i stick with CPU?

Comment: It's also possible that you have a feature enabled that isn't supported in GPU rendering, and this is causing your textures not to be processed, or something along those lines. I'm guessing you have textures on the object in question, because solid magenta is a symptom of missing textures. But in your case they are obviously not missing if CPU rendering works.

Comment: You should always update your driver. Drivers are not going to render your card unusable rather, updating the card driver is essential to make sure your hardware runs properly with the current OS environment you are running. It's a misconception that updating driver will cause your hardware to be damaged or unusable. Such problem only happens with IOS products from apple. I made a quick search on your graphics card online, it seems to support CUDA so the problem must be either the driver or the texture file has been renamed or misplaced.

Comment: @hawkenfox  I updated the driver as suggested, but the most of the images are still coming up pink.  What else can i do?

Comment: @Mentalist , what feature could be causing the issue?  No textures, just images-as-planes, simple PNGs.

Comment: You should pack your texture into the .blend file and upload a copy of the blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - it could just be that you missed something we could spot immediately.

Comment: @WishyQ Ahem... "No textures, just images-as-planes, simple PNGs." What do you think an image is, within the context of a 3D scene's assets? It is a texture. Yes - if you are using *Images-As-Planes*, you are using textures. Think of it like this: Is there pixel data being referenced? If "yes", then your scene relies on images/textures. Why are there two terms? Because "image" can refer to either rendered output from the camera or texture input, whereas "texture" is always input - bitmap data mapped onto an object or the environment in a scene.